# Current week date display on last field

Tags: php, date

From current week number get the previous weeks data but i want print current week date last row?how?
In image Current week displayed on first TD but i want in last TD. how?

```
function getStartAndEndDate($week, $year)
{
    $time = strtotime("1 January $year", time());
    $day = date('w', $time);
    $time += ((7*$week)+1-$day)*24*3600;
    $return[0] = date('Y-n-j', $time);
    $time += 6*24*3600;
    $return[1] = date('Y-m-j', $time);
    return $return[1];
}$i = 1;$week='';

while($i<=4){ $week[]=date('W', strtotime("-$i week"));$i++; }
foreach($week as $wnumber){
$weeknumber=date($wnumber);
$yearnumber=date("Y");
$sunday = getStartAndEndDate($weeknumber,$yearnumber);

}

<th><?php echo $monday.'To'.$sunday; ?> </th>
```

[image: Current week displayed on first TD but i want in last TD]

Comment: you want in reverse order or just current week in last td and others are same as now?

Comment: Yes i got it already. Thanks for suggestion